# Page not found. No umbraco document matches the url '/'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I am trying to run umbraco on my local machine but it gives me error as below.

Page not found
No umbraco document matches the url '/'.

Earlier I had two root content, and I removed other one and kept one only.

Not sure what causing this issue.

Comment: Have you set a hostname on the root node via right click > Culture and hostnames?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://our.umbraco.com/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/73768-no-umbraco-document-matches-the-url#comment-236422

Comment: This occurs on my local machine, host names not required. On further digging I find out there was issue with Doc Type hierarchy which caused it, This is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

On further digging I find out there was issue with Doc Type hierarchy which caused it, This is fixed now.

Comment: I can't find that Doc Type Hierarchy